# Checking if docker build is failed in job

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Job getting success status when docker build got failed
[image]

Ci sample

```
.release:build:template: &release_builder
    image: docker:stable
    stage: release:build
    services:
        - docker:dind
    before_script:
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    after_script:
        - export DOCKER_DEPLOY_IMAGE=$DOCKER_IMAGE_REPO:$(cat DOCKER_TAG)
        - docker build --build-arg DOCKER_BASE_IMAGE --build-arg DOCKER_FRONT_IMAGE --build-arg DOCKER_VENDOR_IMAGE --compress -t $DOCKER_DEPLOY_IMAGE . -f .deploy/docker/$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME/Dockerfile; echo $?
        - docker push $DOCKER_DEPLOY_IMAGE
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - DOCKER_TAG
.release_build_prod:
    <<: *release_builder
    only:
        - tags
    script:
        - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG>DOCKER_TAG
    environment:
        name: prod
```

I was trying to fix this with `docker build ... || exit 1` and also `echo $0?` after build shows nothing and this steps don't help me resolve and issue

So how could i check if docker build command in gitlab finished without errors, or got error and FAILED job

Comment: Why did you add the `echo $?` anyway? you don't need it. try to remove the `;  echo $?` from the end of the command. the results will be printed to the screen if something will fail.

Comment: @AviadLevy the result is already on screenshot.

Comment: I think your problem is that the result of this command is not `exit code 1` because of the `echo` command. did you try to remove it? (sure now you'll have it in the job output but as stdout and not sdterr)

Comment: @AviadLevy just read question please, i've done it with and without echo.